# How to crop thumbnail size, from both width and height sides

Tags: thumbnails

I would like to crop in particular dimensions but I need that to be done on both height and width of the image. Here is a small illustration of what I am trying to do:

[image]

When I try to use this snippet:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-thumbnail', 160, 160, true);
```

or even

```
add_image_size( 'custom-thumbnail', 160, 160, array( 'center', 'center' ));
```

it only crops the horizontal side and so this is what I get:

[image]

And this is what needs to be achieved:

[image]

Is there any way to do that in WordPress? I made a lot of searches on Google but without success.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `add_image_size()` doesn't support this kind of cropping. Someone may answer with a solution but I just wanted to make that clear up front.

Comment: The workaround I'm using right now is to crop the image by 280x280px, then crop the image with CSS (set the size then overflow: hidden;), but then the weight of each thumbnail is higher. I would really like to find a more elegant solution :p